# How to generate random number 1 & 2 instead of 0 & 1 from binomial distribution?

Tags: r, random, binomial-cdf

I would like to generate random number from binomial 1 or 2 instead of the usual 0 and 1. Normally we will use `rbinom(10, 1, 0.4)` to generate either 0 or 1, but is it possible to generate 1 and 2? Or is there any way to convert it?

Comment: you add 1? 1+ rbinom(10, 1, 0.4) ? or you can also do sample(1:2,probs=c(0.4,0.6),replace=TRUE).

Comment: @StupidWolf, please post that as an answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
rbinom(10, 1, 0.4) + 1
```

Or use sample:

```
sample(1:2, 10, prob=c(0.6,0.4), replace=TRUE)
```